# Touchstart and preventDefault blocking child links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link (#my-link) which opens div (#my-menu) on hover in desktop. Inside this div there is small menu.

Now I'm trying to make it work on mobile with tap.

I have this code but I can't click on the links inside the div:

```
$('#my-link').on('touchstart', function (e) {        
     e.preventDefault();        
     $('#my-menu').load(...Im loading content here...);
     $('#my-menu').toggle();
});
```

Any help? I think preventDefault is blocking those links...

Html markup:

```
<a href="example.com" id="my-link">Lorem ipsum</a>
<div id="my-menu">
<a href="example.com">Lorem ipsum</a>
<a href="example.com">Lorem ipsum</a>
<a href="example.com">Lorem ipsum</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to solve the problem wrapping link tag, like:

```
<div id="my-link"><a href="example.com">Lorem ipsum</a></div>
```

and then chaning the first line of script to:

```
$('#my-link > a').on('touchstart', function (e) {
```

Comment: do you need to use an anchor tag?. just use something else like a div instead. show your full mark up and jsfiddle if possible

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use an anchor. It is used when double tap. The markup is very simple. I updated in the question.

Comment: you're saying that preventDefault might be blocking those links, have you tried removing preventDefault and check if they work?

Comment: Just a note: your event handler doesn't receive any event as parameter in your example code. Should be `function(e) {...`, otherwise the `e` you're calling preventDefault on will be out of the intended scope or undefined.

Comment: Right. I corrected it in the code (function(e)).

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` prevents the default action of an element from executing, so in this case the default for a `<a></a>` tag is to send a request to the sever. Some tags don't have default action so you should use those tags like `<div></div>`, `<h1></h1>` or other tags. If you need to use the `<a></a>` tag, do `<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>` which prevents the link from doing anything.

[More Info on event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)